# How can I compare two Django QuerySets and return QuerySet with replacement of the same values from second in first?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

My env is Django `2.0.2` and Python `3.6.1`.

How can I compare two Django QuerySets and return QuerySet with replacement of the same values from second in first?

For example, I have QuerySets:

```
>>> qs_local = PriceLocal.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
>>> print(qs_local)
[{ 'user_id': 1, 'product_id': 1, 'price': 100 }] # one record

>>> qs_world = PriceWorld.objects.all()
>>> print(qs_world)
[{ 'product_id': 1, 'price': 300 }, { 'product_id': 2, 'price': 500 }, ... ] # many records
```

I want to compare this Django QuerySets and return QuerySet, like this:

```
[{ 'product_id': 1, 'price': 100 }, { 'product_id': 2, 'price': 500 }, ...]
```

At this point, we are replacing the same records (with `'product_id': 1`) from second to first QuerySet.

**EDIT:**

My models:

```
class PriceWorld(models.Model):

    product_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class PriceLocal(models.Model):

    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(PriceWorld, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

Comment: Post your model definition?

Comment: This is not possible, since QuerySet should be of one model, not a combination of several.

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking, but you seem to want the elements from PriceWorld that match the product_ids of those elements in PriceLocal related to a specific user ID. So:

```
PriceWorld.objects.filter(product_id__in=PriceLocal.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id))
```

which will be executed as a subquery.

Note, your original query can be written as just `request.user.pricelocal_set.all()`, assuming you haven't changed the related_name, so you can do:

```
PriceWorld.objects.filter(product_id__in=request.user.pricelocal_set.all())
```

which is exactly the same query/subquery but a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about queryset:

but required output can achieve by using:

```
for qs in qs_world:
    if qs['product_id']==qs_local[0]['product_id']:
        qs['price']=qs_local[0]['price']
    else:
        print "hii" 
print qs_world
```